# How to display wp_post by custom field value?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, urls

I am using wooCommerce. How to display posts, when seaching by custom field value.
The goal is when `?s={custom_field_value}` URL is set, to get a result : `?custom_field*={custom_field_value}` And get a list of products which has that `custom_field_value` in custom_field.

*`?custom_field` is the name of custom_field.

Comment: Just note, `s` is a reserved query var which is used for search queries.

Comment: I've updated my answer in line with your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this *by default*, but you can write a query to do it within your theme. It could be a security risk to allow *any* field to be entered in the URL, so you'll need to explicitly detect those that you are wanting.

In your `functions.php`, you could add something like this (untested!):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse230535_custom_posts_by_custom_field' );

function wpse230535_custom_posts_by_custom_field( $query ) {
  if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    $acceptable_fields = array( 'custom-field-1', 'custom-field-2' );
    $meta_query = array();

    foreach( $acceptable_fields as $field ) {
      if ( ! isset( $_GET[$field] ) ) { continue; }

      $meta_query[] = array (
        'key' => $field,
        'value' => sanitize_text_field( $_GET[$field] ),
        'compare' => '=',
      );

    } // end foreach

    if( count( $meta_query ) ) { $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query ); }

  } // end if
} // end function
```

This will take your allowed custom fields - currently `custom-field-1` and `custom-field-2`, check whether they're set in the query string (via the [`$_GET[]` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)), and then if so, [sanitize them](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) and add them to a [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).

You'll need to replace the allowed field names with the ones you want, of course. As an example, this code would, when one visits `http://www.example.com/?custom-field-1=fieldvalue`, only show posts that have a custom field called `custom-field-1`, with the exact value of `fieldvalue`. You can add as many fields as you want.

For further reference on making queries by custom fields, you can see the [WP Meta Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments). Hope this helps!

Comment: *No, you can't retrieve a post, by custom field, directly by URL* Not true. You can pass anything through the URL and let that alter the main query accordingly. All you need is to check for your custom `$_GET` variable in the URL, and then use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query accordingly

Comment: @PieterGoosen True, I didn't elaborate on that though because I didn't know if that's what the OP wanted - it was unclear if they wanted to do a dynamic query as such or just a static query.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Post updated in line with OP's edit.